# I want to insert text using JavaScript when I click on button. But ```.value()``` doesn't seems to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code snippet. Please help me out with this bug :/
What I want to do is when I click the button it should insert some value in the input bar

```js
function insertText() {
  try {
    document.querySelector('#input').value('Clicked');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("ERROR")
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.btn {
  height: 40vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.btn>button {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="" id="input">
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <button oncanplay="insertText()" id="butt">INSERT SOME TEXT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please correct your snippet it gives a script error. InsertText function doesn’t do anything so I guess there is a bit missing.

Comment: `oncanplay` doesn't listen clicks on a button, use `onclick` instead, or rather use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Also, `value` is not a method in native `input` element, it's a property, which you set by assigning it a string.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function insertText(){
            try{
                document.querySelector('#input').value = "Lorem Ipsum";
            }catch(err){
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
        }
```

```css
*{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container{
            height: 60vh;
            width: 100vw;
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
            border: 2px solid blue;
        }
        .btn{
            height: 40vh;
            border: 2px solid red;
            width: 100vw;
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
        }
        .btn>button{
            padding: 10px 40px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <input type="text" value="" id="input">
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <button onclick="insertText()" id="butt">INSERT SOME TEXT</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Some explanations on the changes would be nice.

Comment: You had a mistake in this line - 
Your Code: `document.querySelector('#input').value('Clicked');` 

My Code: `document.querySelector('#input').value = "Lorem Ipsum";`

Comment: Thank you so much, man! This really helped out : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to add the text to the input when the button is clicked.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#setBtnID").click(function () {
                    $("input:text").val("Hello World!");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.btn {
  height: 40vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.btn>button {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#setBtnID").click(function () {
                $("input:text").val("Hello World!");
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="" id="input">
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <button  id="setBtnID">INSERT SOME TEXT</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should note that this uses jQuery.